# JavaFX or FXML. What is the difference?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have newly started to learn javafx to build desktop apps. But i don't understand one thing. Here is my problem:
We can create a gui by writing codes, like that:

---

[image]

---

Or, we can create gui with scene builder, like this:

[image]

---

If the second method is available, why should we use writing codes, like where to put this label or button or whatever.?

I'm new, so i don't know if the second method has any weakness.

Comment: In my experience builders and pre-built software are good for small tasks, demos, or projects that do not require a lot of changes. Because as soon as you are at a point where you have to make an application that has to behave just "so" for the client, you are left with hacking at the builder and its code which is usually very time consuming and not easily done. Both methods have their uses but it depends on the situation.

Comment: Just use whichever style fits what you need to do best (and you can use both within the same application if you need). FXML separates the layout code from the controller code nicely, and for many UI designs will be best. But if, for example, you had a 20x20 array of buttons (or some other component), it would be far more convenient to create that in code using arrays and loops than it would to create all 400 controls individually in FXML

Comment: FXML is static. It is good for fixed layouts, like dialog boxes and standard forms. But if the `Scene` is dynamic, you can use FXML, and have to call the API directly. FXML is for your convenience, to help separate layout from logic, but it is not the solution for all use cases.

Comment: Fxml actually works by using classes available in java. Without existing java logic the fxml wouldn't work so surely anything created using a fxml could be created from java code only. As for why fxml exists? It's a nice feature, isn't it? Why not offer it to simplify ui creation. Furthermore it has the benefit of not requiring compilation.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm new, so i don't know if the second method has any weakness.

Time permitting, write your UI separately using both approaches!

Seriously, if you're new and want to learn the pitfalls of either approach, there's generally no better way than to get hands on with a few scenarios, get a grasp on both toolkits and see which approach you prefer in different situations.

There are clear cases when one will become better than the other, but the "in-between" cases then often come down to personal preference (and in the case where it's not just you developing, team-based preference and adhering to your company's code style requirements as well.)

Answer (score 2):

I mostly work in FXML myself, I like the WYSIWYG approach of the SceneBuilder, but I had cases where I went back to coded UI.

For example I have an application where the user answers up to 10 questions. The questions or their amount is not known at compile time. I create the labels and checkboxes for the questions at runtime in a GridPane. The GridPane is part of a FXML layout. This can be done solely in FXML using ListView and custom ListCells but it is substantially more work and I do not need Cell reusing because there are too few questions.

Also it can be necessary to have 10x10 buttons, putting 100 buttons in FXML is no fun. I used that when I implemented a game [like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/LightsOutIllustration.svg/400px-LightsOutIllustration.svg.png) on Android.

Also when you have a lot of different views that are all very similar except for small positioning difference you might want to create them in code instead of making multiple nearly identical FXML files.